# Get the data from the redux store on demand (onClick)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to get the data from the store not on component render but only on button click (or other event).

Imagine the situation where there is `BooksList` component that renders multiple `BookItem` components. A single `BookItem` component has a button which fires `handleExportClick` as presented below:

```
const BookItem = ({ book }) => {
  const highlights = useSelector((state) => 
      state.highlights.filter(q => q[1].book === book.title)
    )
  
  const handleExportClick = () => {
    bookExport(highlights)
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleExportClick}>Export</Button>
  )
```

This solution works but it has a major flaw. The `highlights` variable is calculated for every component (every `BookItem`). This is not optimal, because the data is required only when user clicks **Export** button.

I tried solving this problem by moving `useSelector` inside `handleExportClick` but this doesn't work.

```
const BookItem = ({ book }) => {
  const handleExportClick = () => {
    const highlights = useSelector((state) => 
      state.highlights.filter(q => q[1].book === book.title)
    )
    
    bookExport(highlights)
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleExportClick}>Export</Button>
  )
}
```

This gives

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Which is understandable.

What's the current pattern for getting the data from the store but only on demand?

---

### Solution

Use `useStore` hook for directly accessing store.

```
import { useStore } from 'react-redux'

const BookItem = ({ book }) => {
  const store = useStore()
  
  const handleExportClick = () => {
    const highlights = store.getSate().highlights.filter(q => q[1].book === book.title)
    bookExport(highlights)
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleExportClick}>Export</Button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to inject the store to the component.
Next time use the search option https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store

I'm closing this thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject `store` instance to this component using `useStore` and then use `store.getState()` when needed.